# Rails 3. How to add files to the initialisation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering how you added files to be included in the initialisation of a rails app.

At the moment I'm keeping a few files in the model folder because I know the are including.

How do you specify any file to be included, I would rather the files are in lib folder.

Comment: Could you explain more abou what these files do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autoload `/lib` folder by adding this line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

It's probably just commented now.

But if all you need is just some simple [app configuring](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html), put it in `config/initializers` like John said.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the `config/initializers` directory.